# Tools/programmes to prevent unconscious biases on CVs?

Tags: resume, human-resources, diversity, equality

Does anyone know of a tool or programme that will help highlight and prevent unconscious biases on candidates CVs?
Deleting name on CVs is already step one, but would like a tool to simplify to identify possible words/statements.

Comment: How can a bias be unconscious?

Comment: Maybe hire an employee to rewrite each resume before you look at it!

Comment: I would recommend not buying into the pile of crap that suggests we all have "unconscious bias", whatever that is. Just hire the best person, or something.

Comment: Here you go guys: https://diversity.ucsf.edu/resources/unconscious-bias

Comment: Tool: Use your brain and don't just go with what 'feels good'.  Hire people based on things like "The best skill set" and "The most experienced."  If you are really letting things like someone's *name* influence you, you are not of sound mind to be hiring people.

Comment: @RichardU - That would be a bias that you have but that you are not aware that you have.

Comment: An intern with good instructions and a black marker can make short work of a fuzzy technical problem.

Comment: It's silly to deny we all have unconscious biases (I can't believe people still deny that lol), but why is unconscious bias a bad thing? It's the gift of fear. Your body and mind have certain emotional and visceral reactions to certain names etc. and that can be a good warning sign against hiring certain employees. Don't ignore your biases, they can save your life!

Comment: @StephanBranczyk But a tool can minimize it.  For example, by removing references to gender (using non-gendered versions of words) and anonymizing the name/email until after a decision is made to interview or not.  Studies have shown that a minority sounding name will get 50% fewer callbacks than a white one (source: http://www.nber.org/digest/sep03/w9873.html) and this bias can easily be avoided.

Comment: @TangoFoxtrot your unconscious biases are not just useless, but actively harmful, 100% of the time when you're looking at a CV.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk as far as I'm concerned, either impeccable grammar matters (in which case it's not an unconscious bias) or it doesn't, in which case it really shouldn't hurt the applicants' case. People who aren't perfectly fluent in a language can still be the best candidate for many jobs.

Comment: This does not make sense.   How would you test that the tool is doing its job (i.e. preventing bias that, by definition, you don't know you have, and therefore, could never test against)?

Comment: @Erik 100% of the time? What if your biases bias you towards the best candidate, just by chance?

Comment: @TangoFoxtrot you wouldn't know that it did. And even if you did know, it would only make your unconscious bias even stronger and problematic the next time around. "Wrong approach, right conclusion by luck" is bad because the next time, you'll use the same approach and you might not be lucky. And you might blame something other than the approach, because it worked last time after all.

Comment: @Erik Huh, I actually agree WRT "Wrong approach, right conclusion by luck"... Guess I just don't see the problem with the rest, though.

Comment: @TangoFoxtrot well; I might see where you're coming from if you can give me an example of a common name that would trigger an unconscious bias for good reasons. I can't imagine any reason why someone's name would be a good judge of their skill or ability.

Comment: @Erik There are obvious examples: Theodore, Katherine, Mary, William, which point to highly educated, classy, and professional applicant. Christopher/Christina/Christa etc. indicate the applicant is a Christian or was at least raised so (as a Christian myself, I'd guess it's on average a good thing in the US). A name can also indicate age: Dorothy is likely older than Kaylee, which can be good if you're looking for experience.

Comment: @TangoFoxtrot all of these are really harmful. There is no reason to believe any of those assumptions would be true.

Comment: @Erik Sure, they'd not be true all the time, but on average, they would bias you towards the best candidate. Not 100% of the time. But sometimes.

Comment: @TangoFoxtrot on average, they would not bias you towards the best candidate, unless you got lucky and the best candidate just HAPPENED to have the right name. If you follow this in actual hiring, you are almost certainly making terrible hiring mistakes.

Comment: @Erik "unless you got lucky and the best candidate just HAPPENED to have the right name" Doesn't require much luck. Names are associated with characteristics for a reason. Of course I don't use this in actual hiring - at least not consciously, which is the whole point of this thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61894/discussion-between-erik-and-tango-foxtrot).

Answer (score 5):

If you have an online application system, set it up so the system assigns each applicant an applicant number at the start of the process. Only the system will know the association between each applicant number and the name of the applicant.

Let's say John Smith starts his application. He's assigned the applicant number #123456. He completes and submits his application. When employees at your company review applications, they see an application belonging to #123456. They do not see John Smith's name.

Then, if the employees select applicant #123456 for a phone screen or an interview, the system will advise them of the applicant's name and other personal information (such as phone number, email address, etc.) at that point so that they can contact the applicant.

Obviously, unconscious (and conscious) bias can still come into play at the interview. But the point is not to eliminate unconscious bias. It's to minimize its impact on your applicant pool.

Depending on the type of work your company does, you can go the whole nine yards and [have applicants audition from behind a curtain](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.90.4.715) ;). This isn't practical for a lot of fields, of course - it's impossible in mine for instance.

---

*Source of idea:* Years ago I was grading student assignments. Most assignments were submitted in person and contained both the name and the student number of the submitting student. But a few assignments were submitted through an online system, and those didn't contain any identifying information except the student number. (It was a glitch, not deliberate, because the system admins weren't aware of it.) I found it unnerving at first because I didn't know whose work I was looking at. But it became an experiment to guess whose work it was. I thought I could, but I couldn't - in a class of 25 students, I'd guess maybe 2 correctly (and this was often because they had talked to me in-person about their assignments before submission). It was eye-opening.

Edited to add, I do not agree with eliminating certain words or statements as this materially changes the content of the CV/resume. It's no longer about race, sex or other biases. (Plus, based on my above experience, I wouldn't say the work of male vs female students is materially different in how it's written etc. It is written in the same 'sterile' professional language!)

Answer (score 3):

You can grep out keywords of interest but then you'd end up with a buzzword counter. I doubt that's what you're after.

You're asking for a tool to eliminate evaluator bias. You can simply add more evaluators, and each CV gets scored by many people. Assuming you trust your colleagues, you can turn the (rather ideologically charged) concept of *unconscious bias* into a positive, where the bias works in favour of the company's culture.

There's no mind-reading software, and there's no software that spits out bias-proof content. At the end of the day you have to rethink and improve your hiring process.

Answer (score 0):

The wording, spelling, grammar, and presentation on a resumes are all criteria used to weed out unsuitable candidates.

Altering those will give you an unrealistic view of the candidate.

As far as unconscious bias is concerned, I think you're being a little bit paranoid. If you're reading the resume of "John Smith" and are impressed with his achievements, then replacing that name with a foreign one *shouldn't matter*, unless you have a bias against people who might be of immigrant descent. If you do, then you're going to reject the candidate in the interview phase instead of the resume review stage anyway, so it makes little difference.

Comment: Only there's *lots* of evidence that replacing the name with a foreign one (or a female one), *does* affect peoples evaluation of a CV.  I don't know whether the bias at interview time is better or worse.

Comment: @MartinBonner it's not hard to take out names of resumes/cv's. But other than that the rest of the content is needed for a full evaluation of the candidate, else you're left with something a computer could do and you have the problem of looking for buzzwords, one way or the other. The point of the cv and resume is to set you apart one way or the other

Comment: @AndreiROM http://www.nber.org/digest/sep03/w9873.html   Research shows that minority sounding names get 50% fewer callbacks then when the exact same resume is sent with a white name.

Comment: @gabesechan - spare me the SJW "research". White names ... that's a new one.

Comment: @AndreiROM do you have counter evidence? No, just name calling? So you're incapable of making reasoned arguments, got it.

Comment: @gabesechan - what name calling might you be referring to? Also, please define what a "white" name might possibly be. Let's take "John Smith" as an example. Is this name a label that defines culture, color, or religion? He might be white, black, or some other race. Would someone with a Persian name be coloured? You might be surprised.

Comment: SJW. General rule- anyone who uses that term can have his opinion totally ignored. You aren't disputing the research with facts, you're name calling to detract from it. As for your other question- read the research. Or are you really saying different names don't statistically belong to different ethnic groups?

Comment: @Gabesechan - you ignored my arguments altogether. I will answer yours, however. Names CAN be an indicative of ethnicity, but they are unreliable. There's 5th generation immigrants with foreign sounding names who are North American through and through. Someone might also marry into an immigrant family and change their name. And so, please tell me, what exactly might a "white name" be?

Comment: Once again, read the research. It explains things.